# Ribbon cable reconect to IDC

Tags: ribbon-cable

Can ribbon cable be reconect to its IDC after it's been pulled out from the IDC? Also can a IDC be disconnected from its connection point on the mother board, then reconected after its ribbon cable has been reconected to the IDC?[image][image]

Answer (score 7):

"IDC" -> "[Insulation displacement connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation-displacement_connector)".

That's not an IDC connector, it's a [flat flex cable (FFC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable). And yes, you should be able to reconnect it. There are typically small tabs on the mating connector that you can pull back, then you insert the cable, and then push the tabs back in to lock the cable into the connector. As long as you do not damage the tabs, these connectors can be connected/disconnected many times.